# Update ODM 8.10 to 8.11. issue with JNDI

Tags: websphere, odm

im trying to update ODM from 8.10 to 8.11, however the following error occurs:

ADMA0007E: A validation error occurred in task Mapping resource references to resources. The Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) name is not specified for resource reference eis/XUConnectionFactory in module Rule Execution Server Console with EJB name .
ADMA0007E: A validation error occurred in task Mapping resource references to resources. The Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) name is not specified for resource reference jdbc/resdatasource in module Rule Execution Server Console with EJB name ."

From the DMGR console there is a successful connection:
The test connection operation of data source Decision Server - Datasource on server nodeagent at node WAS_TEST_ODM01_Node01 was successful.

Everything seems to be mapped correctly, I will be happy if someone faces a similar problem to share the knowledge.

How can i check if the resources are maped correctly